# asterisk color for edit text not showing red color in xml layout

Tags: android, xml, android-textinputedittext

Hi in the below code simple material design TextInputEditText using to display the edittext.Text with Mandratory symbol(*) but my problem is * is not displaying in red color.
Can any one help to resolve it
Xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

                                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                                            android:id="@+id/subject"
                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                            android:textSize="16dp"
                                            android:textColorHint="@color/tabs"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:hint="@string/subject"
                                            />
                                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

java:

```
subject=rootView.findViewById(R.id.subject);
            subject.setHint(subject.getHint()+" "+Html.fromHtml ( "<font color=\"#ff0000\">" + "* " + "</font>"+" "));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with

```
(Html.fromHtml(subject.getHint()+"<font color='#FF0000'>*</font>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I Resolved the Problem

updated:

```
subject.setHint(Html.fromHtml ( subject.getHint()+" "+"<font color=\"#ff0000\">" + "* " + "</font>"));
```